# Backbone.js two models affecting each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a table, its rows are models in collection, each row have two columns with inputs, rate per hour and hours, model also have attribute `total`, which is basically just `rate_per_hour*hours`, and it's being updated as user changes hours or rate per hour. You can add new rows and delete them as well. This, I believe, I managed to do the right backbone way.

Now first part I'm not sure about, I need to have a div which contains sums of hours and total, I've also managed to do this, using a function (which basically just loops thru models in collection, sums their attributes and then updates my div using jquery), change events on models, after setting the new attributes, are calling this function. It's outside all views/collections/models. Not sure if this is the proper way of doing this, but it works.

Now the worst part where I failed miserably, realized my code was probably wrong from the very beginning. Under that div with totals is another input, called discount, what it is supposed to do is count discount percentage `((value of discount/my total sum)*100)`, and then update the rates in table so it shows both the old one and the one with discount applied.

#### Actual problem here:

What I don't get is how should I connect the bottom part (totals and discount - see screenshot) with the upper part, should the bottom part be another model, with attributes total, discount and hours, and have it's own view instead of being a simple div? But then how would it work, how could one model (discount), affect models in the collection, and vice versa, adding a row would need to affect totals and discount percent?

Here's screenshot of how it's supposed to work from a working jquery-only version where I didn't use backbone yet.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/J3uyilH.png]

Will post code if requested as well, but it's now kind of bloated with my attempts to solve it by using jquery events, my own simple objects containing those totals and shizzle wizzle.

Comment: Is the question really "Why do I need 2 models"? Remember you can have separate views that use data from the same models and use the data accordingly.

Comment: No I definitely don't mind having two models, I just 1) didn't know whether those "totals" should be a model 2) how could changes of collection affect that model and vice versa, how could change on "discount" affect data in collection

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're getting at is an issue with *modeling your data*. Sometimes it helps to take a step back and ask yourself "what are the things i'm working with?".

It seems like each of the rows you mention represents an 'activity' (each with a name, and rate). You also have a collection of these activities, which is good. Now you could ask, "what kind of thing does this entire piece of ui (represented by the screenshot in it's entirety) represent?". If we called this piece of ui an ActivitiesView, it could listen for UI interaction (changing of the fields) which would update the collection. Once the collection changes, it triggers the view to re-render with the updated totals.

In this example, the discount field on the collection is just a convenience and used by the collection to update it's children.

```
var Activity = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { discount: 0 }
});

var ActivityCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.on("change:discount", this.updateDiscounts, this);
    },
    model: activity,
    totalAmount: function () { /* ...iterate over items, return total amount, factoring in total */ },
    totalHours: function () { /* ...iterate over items, return total hours... */ },
    updateDiscounts: function (discount) { /* ...iterate over items, updating each item's discount */}
});

var ActivitiesView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    "change input.discount": "applyDicsounts"
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "change", this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
  }

  render: function() {
    this.$el.find('.totalAmount').text(this.collection.totalAmount());
    this.$el.find('.totalHours').text(this.collection.totalHours());  
  },

  applyDicsounts: function (e) {
    var new_discount = e.target.value; // should probably validate this
    this.collection.set({ discount: new_discount });
  }

});

var myCollection = new ActivityCollection();
var myActivitiesView = new ActivitiesView({ collection: myCollection });
```

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely the issue, the other is that I started playing around with Backbone like yesterday. 

Anyway, each row simply represent entry in database, its model stucture is simply {rate: 1200, hours: 10}, that selectbox updates rate(each activity have a different rate) for the entry. It's also got another select box with a person, but for the sake of simplicity a removed it. 

So model can have a collection as an attribute? Ok, so I'd have model project, with {dicount: 0, total:0, entries: new EntriesCollection}? then how would change on "discount" affect models in the collection?

Comment: The way i was thinking about it, the 'discount' field would only apply to 'project' models, and thus be calculated against the project total (not each individual item). The DB model for an activity could include a foreign key to it's associated 'project', if you wanted to relate them that way (a framework like Rails would make this easier).

Comment: Apparently I suck at explaining what I'm trying to do. Anyway, visible rate discount on each entry is a must, it's essential for the app to work. Also backend is fine. What I'm trying to do is pretty much all just for the visuals, so the user can see live how are those numbers changing as he adds new rows, changes activities, changes number in the hours input. So again, what needs to happen is  totals(current rate * hours) are summed -> discount ratio is calculated(value of discount/sum of totals) -> loop thru entries and apply discount(boths old and new val is shown) -> new rate summed

Comment: also it's gonna be set, there's another similar table under this one and there total total made from totals of those two tables, the other table is gonna be without discounts, just one input, so it's gonna be easier, but I'll still have to decide whether that total total is gonna be another model...

Comment: "Ok, so I'd have model project, with {dicount: 0, total:0, entries: new EntriesCollection}? then how would change on "discount" affect models in the collection?" 
Models are just objects which are always called by reference, so it will always update the collection that moment. You can do stuff in the collection (i.e. change values on others when a particular model is changed) by adding the 'change' event. If you think about it, you would never hard code a total into an excel spreadsheet would you? It would be generated from the values of many other cells (scalar variables).

Comment: Gonna give it a try then, but is this kind of nesting the proper way? I seems a bit hacky..

Comment: Okay then, I think I understand the issue better now. I agree with what marksyzm says, and I updated my 'project' model to reflect total as a method rather than a value. You could simplify this further by just adding the 'discount' and the 'total' onto the collection itself.

Comment: I updated my example yet again, this time each model carries it's own discount field which can be updated from the collection, and thus from the view.

Comment: It's a little different from what you and marksyzm suggested first time though, in your example, totals and discounts are part of the collection, rather then them being a model and the collection being an attribute to that model..